# correct approach for storing and display a state specific to Users

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a page that lists questions (in C programming :-) ) that are completed by users. Say, there are 10 and every logged in user has access to these.

page to be displayed is something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Test desc</th>
<th>Test state</th>
</tr>
{% for t in test%}
<tr>
<td>{{ t.desc }}</td>
<td>'display a image  if it is completed else another image'</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

User is forwarded to this page from views.py

```
def test(request):
    cProblems = Problems_c.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('subject/test.html', {'list':cProblems})
```

I need to know 2 things.

1. How to store this additional User specific information in django.
2. How to display them in webpage

Answer (score 1):

First, please use [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) rather than render_to_response(). This will save you from common gotchas.

> How to store this additional User specific information in django

See the documentation about [storing additional user information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

> How to display them in webpage

You can use the generic [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView):

1. **Import DetailView in urls.py**, i.e. `from django.views import generic`
2. **Import the User model in urls.py**, i.e. `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`
3. **Add an url for that in urls.py**, i.e. `url(r'^/user/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view({'model': user, 'context_object_name': 'object'}))`
4. **Create the template**, in templates/auth/user_detail.html
5. **Open url /user/1/** to see the rendered template

Your template can look like this:

```
<h1>This is the page of {{ object.username }}</h1>

<p>Additional info: {{ object.get_profile.your_extra_field }}</p>
```

Of course, you should have a base template say templates/base.html that would look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block head_title %}{% endblock %} - your website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

And your user_detail.html template should use it, see [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#templates):

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}

{% block head_title %}Details of {{ object.username }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>This is the page of {{ object.username }}</h1>

<p>Additional info: {{ object.get_profile.your_extra_field }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

As you're new to Django, I highly recommend that you install [admindoc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/) which provides autogenerated documentation based on your project.